# How can you use Spring's @Validated with Java modules without getting InaccessibleObjectException?

Tags: java, spring, bean-validation, java-platform-module-system

When using `@Validated` with Java's modules I get an InaccessibleObjectException:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to bind properties under 'abc' to com.example.demo.ConfigProperties$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4dbae57f:

    Reason: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field java.lang.String com.example.demo.ConfigProperties.hello accessible: module com.example.demo does not "opens com.example.demo" to unnamed module @163370c2

Action:

Update your application's configuration
```

**How can I debug this to find out the library which is causing this in the unnamed module?**

**How can I get this to work (without resorting to opening the entire module)?**

Full code:

```java
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("abc")
@Validated
public class ConfigProperties {
    @NotNull String hello;
    @NotNull String byeBye;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ConfigProperties{hello='" + hello + '\'' +", byeBye='" + byeBye + '\'' + '}';
    }
}
```

module-info.java:

```java
module com.example.demo {
    opens com.example.demo to spring.beans, spring.boot, spring.core;
    exports com.example.demo;

    requires java.validation;
    requires org.slf4j;
    requires spring.beans;
    requires spring.boot;
    requires spring.boot.autoconfigure;
    requires spring.core;
    requires spring.context;
}
```